# What does it mean to be an equivalent repay scheme? (sinking fund vs. amortization)

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

I am having trouble solving the following problem which seems simple, but I cannot quite get it right.

> Smith can repay a loan $L=250,000$ in one of two ways
>
> 1), 30 annual payments based on amortization at $i=.12$
>
> 2), 30 annual interest payments to the lender at rate $i=.10$, along with 30 level annual deposits to a sinking fund earning rate $j$
>
> find the value of $j$ that makes the schemes **equivalent**

I am not 100% clear what they mean by equivalent.  Smith is borrowing $L$ initially so it cannot be the present value of the loan.  The two guesses that I have is the "total outlay being equivalent" and the "future value" being equivalent.  I was not sure if I would get the same result, so I am doing the following calculations assuming the former case.

1), 30 level payments $K$ for an amortized loan is simply

$$K=\frac{L}{a_{\overline{30}\rceil .12}} \approx 31035.91$$

Thus the total outlay is again, simply $30K$.

2), Each outlay of the other scheme $M$
is

$$M=Li+\frac{L}{s_{\overline{30}\rceil j}}$$

so the total outlay through 30 yrs is equal to $30M$

So I am thinking that since these values are equal to each other I am solving for the equation for $j$ where

$$\frac{1}{a_{\overline{30}\rceil .12}}=.12+\frac{1}{s_{\overline{30}\rceil j}}$$

I used a graphing calculator to solve for $j$, but it gave me $j=i$ which is not the answer (It's supposed to be .021322)

Thanks.

*Edited

Comment: Hey @hyg17!  Did you try setting up an equation of value to determine equivalence between the amortization scheme and the sinking fund scheme?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoDris what does it mean for the "schemes to be equivalent"?  I recalculated the equation I had and it gave me j=.12, which is not the answer...

Comment: Equivalence is this:  At a certain point in time, the current value of the funds in the amortization scheme is equal to the current value of the funds in the sinking fund scheme.

Comment: Hmm... could you elaborate a bit more?  Would not the current value of both schemes be L?  Or are you talking about how much Smith has to pay?

Comment: Aha!  I think I see where your error is.  $i = 0.10$ in the equation involving the annuity symbols.

Comment: OMG I feel so ridiculous... thank you so much.  I will try this again.

Comment: That's fine!  =)

Comment: I'm an actuarial science major myself, so I know how tricky and messy these formulas and symbols can become... =)

Comment: Interesting.  I self study all of these so Stack Exchange is my huge source of help.  I already passed the probability exam, so now I am working on financial mathematics.

Comment: That's good.  Keep it up!  I passed the old Exams 100 and 110 from way back.  So I was given credit for Exam P.  Dunno when I could get down to studying for Exam FM.  =)

Comment: You should look up the Exam FM reviewers by Finan and another one by Guo.  Good luck with your actuarial exam!  ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! I think I see where your error is. $i=0.10$ in the equation involving the annuity symbols.

Comment: I got the answer correct.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help!  =)